# Unexpected Identifier in Typescript Interface in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, typescript, webstorm

I'm trying to understand why I'm having `Unexpected Identifier` error in Typescript (1.4) Interface in chrome

The code:

```
interface IMessage {
    target : string;
    type : string;
    data : Object;
}
```

[image]

I wonder maybe it is *.js.map file generated incorrectly. I use last WebStorm to generate them. The Imessage.js.map for that consists with that that content:

```
{"version":3,"file":"IMessage.js","sourceRoot":"","sources":["IMessage.ts"],"names":[],"mappings":"AAIC"}
```

[image]

IMessage.js

```
//# sourceMappingURL=IMessage.js.map
```

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, you are loading your TypeScript code `.ts` in Chrome while you should load your `.js` files.

When you write TypeScript files you can compile them with the compiler (`tsc`) and it outputs `.js` file which you can load in the browser nodejs or other JavaScript compatible stuff!

Comment: *.js *.map.js and *.ts all are there.
i guess then I will not be able to debug by typescript sources if I'm not loading them to chrome.

Comment: You should load the `*.js` in chrome and it well detect the sourcemap through the comment in your j's file. So you can debug the .ts code :)